# Hide/remove scrollbar of Webview on Mac OS

Tags: macos, scrollbar

I have a html file contains an iframe inside it. I integrated this html with Mac OS app. I use webview to show my html on this Mac app. iframe has a scrollbar, but I want to remove this scroll. I added below css to remove that scroll bar. It works when running html file on browser(chrome), but it does not work on Mac OS app. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}
```

[image]